# In c# I would like to increment an integer every time another integer increases by a set amount

Tags: c#, integer

I am trying to perform this task in c#.

I have 2 Integers...
int TotalScore
int ExtraLife

I would like to increase "ExtraLife" by 1 every time the TotalScore increases by at least 5?

Here is an example...

```
public void Example(int scored)
{
    TotalScore += scored;

    if (TotalScore > 0 && TotalScore % 5 == 0)
    {
        ExtraLife++;

        // it seems that the ExtraLife will only increment if the
        // total score is a multiple of 5.
        // So if the TotalScore were 4 and 2 were passed
        // in as the argument, the ExtraLife will not increment.

    }

}
```

Comment: Divide TotalScore by 5 and if remainder is 0 then increment `ExtraLife` int

Comment: Do you even *need* the `ExtraLife` variable if it's always just `TotalScore/5`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, reading into the variable names, it appears he's making a type of game. As such, it seems reasonable that ExtraLife could decrement at some point. If so, the ratio of TotalScore/5 wouldn't hold.

Comment: what it is returning? it should return `19` and you can skip first part of if as you always start `TotalScore > 0`

Comment: I think that my example will need refined, as it seems that my current miscalculation happens when the TotalScore is incremented by values that do not calculate to a multiple of the desired increment.

Comment: can your totalscore increase by more than 1 at any time? i think only then the above calculation can fail.

Comment: Yes NoviceProgrammer. And that seems to be my issue.

Comment: Did you checked my answer?

Comment: I am going through it right now :)

Comment: @reido113, have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
class Whatever
{
    private int extraLifeRemainder;

    private int totalScore;
    public int TotalScore
    {
        get { return totalScore; }
        set
        {
            int increment = (value - totalScore);
            DoIncrementExtraLife(increment);
            totalScore = value;
        }
    }

    public int ExtraLife { get; set; }

    private void DoIncrementExtraLife(int increment)
    {
        if (increment > 0)
        {
            this.extraLifeRemainder+= increment;
            int rem;
            int quotient = Math.DivRem(extraLifeRemainder, 5, out rem);
            this.ExtraLife += quotient;
            this.extraLifeRemainder= rem;
        }
    }
}

private static void Main()
{
    Whatever w = new Whatever();
    w.TotalScore += 8;
    w.TotalScore += 3;

    Console.WriteLine("TotalScore:{0}, ExtraLife:{1}", w.TotalScore, w.ExtraLife);
    //Prints 11 and 2
}
```

Comment: In reconsidering this answer, I think it's on the right track. I have a *little* heartburn over seeing the logic embedded in a property setter, would like to see updating the score as a method call, and probably have the properties be read-only.

Comment: This seems to do the trick! I will try to build from this. Thanks Sriram

Comment: @reido113 You may need to [accept any one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) which helped you. So that it will be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public void Sample()
{
   int ExtraLife = 0;

   for (int TotalScore = 1; TotalScore <= 100; TotalScore++)
   {         
      if (TotalScore % 5 == 0)
          ExtraLife++;
   }
}
//ExtraLife = 20
```

**UPDATE**:

As example has been updated in the question, it seems that `ExtraLife = TotalScore / 5;` should give you right value. You don't need to increment `ExtraLife` integer:

```
 public void Example(int scored)
 {
    TotalScore += scored;    
    ExtraLife = TotalScore / 5;
 }
```

Comment: That won't work properly if you increment except 1. For example by 2 or 3

Comment: Increment by 2 or 3 where it is required? I missed something in question?

Comment: try `for (int TotalScore = 1; TotalScore <= 100; TotalScore+=2)` and see.

Comment: But my question is why `+=2` in for loop?

Comment: `I would like to increase "ExtraLife" by 1 every time the TotalScore increases by 5` is the question, and your answer fails to do that.

Comment: @Sriram, thanks. Can you check updated code? I have added another method. Would like to have feedback. By the way your solution is great :)

Comment: Try `Example(12, 11);` still returns `1` it should be `2`. FYI refer my answer to see how I solved it.